# Reactjs: Unexpected Token

Tags: node.js, npm, sublimetext3, webpack, reactjs

I'm trying to follow the tutorial here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html

Simply trying to build the following, either within Sublime Text 3, or webpack:

```
// ReactTest.js
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

console.log("Hello");

ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

I've installed Sublime Text 3, as well as the following packages via Package Control, Install:

- Babel for syntax highlighting
- Sublime Linter (3) for error checking
- Sublime Linter-contrib-eslint (an interface for eslint)

I have already installed node via homebrew:

```
brew install node
```

Used NPM to install the following:

```
npm install webpack -g
npm install --save react react-dom babel-preset-react babel-preset-es2015
npp install jsxhint -g
npm install -g jshint
```

From what I understand, this should be everything I need to run *either of the two* options:

---

1. Use Sublime Text 3's build:  I added a new 'build system' for Sublime Text by *Tools -> Build System -> New Build System* and created the file:

   { "cmd" : ["/usr/local/bin/node", "$file"], "selector":"source.js" }

which is saved to *me/Library/ApplicationSupport/SublimeText3/Packages/user/node.sublime.build* on my osx.

I run *Tools -> Build* to build which results in:

```
/Users/me/Desktop/Test/ReactTest.js:8
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
  ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['/usr/local/bin/node', '/Users/me/Desktop/Test/ReactTest.js']]
[dir: /Users/me/Desktop/Test]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

---

2. Also tried to do the same thing using webpack with the following command:

   webpack ReactTest.js Bundle.js

Which results in:

```
ERROR in ./ReactTest.js
Module parse failed: /Users/me/Desktop/Test/ReactTest.js Line 8: Unexpected token <
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| 
| ReactDOM.render(
|   <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
|   document.getElementById('example')
| );
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: Completely new to all of these technologies.  Here's a screenshot of my project in Sublime Text.

[image]

EDIT 2:  The .babelrc file, which I've copied from the web:

```
{
  "plugins": ["transform-react-jsx"],
  "ignore": [
    "foo.js",
    "bar/**/*.js"
  ]
}
```

Comment: do you have .babelrc configured in root?

Comment: show your webpack.js

Comment: @RajaSekar No, by default .babelrc does not exist in /Users/me/.  Where would webpack.js need to be?

Comment: Actually you are using jsx, so u need to configure loader in webpack to transpile your jsx to js. check https://webpack.github.io/docs/loaders.html

Comment: I feel like I'm going down a rabbit hole.  Why does the tutorial here make it seem so simple: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html? Under 'Using React from npm' Maybe it's just leaving all the webpack config out...

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using JSX in your code, you have to transpile to js using loaders in webpack.

   module.exports = {
       entry: 'ReactTest.js',
       output: {
           path: path.join(__dirname, './dist'),
           filename: 'bundle.js'
       },
       module: {
           loaders: [
               {
                   test: /.js$/,
                   exclude : /node_modules/,
                   loader: 'babel',
                   query: {
                       presets: ['react', 'es2015']
                   }
               }
           ]
       }
   };
2. Make sure you configured .babelrc in root path if you are using ES2015 syntax
3. copy and use the below webpack config in your webpack.config.js
4. run **webpack** in root folder
5. include bundle.js in your index.html.

Let me know if you face any difficulties

Comment: Where does the webpack config belong?  I assume it's just the snippet that you've included here.